# How do I prevent Unity-2D Launcher from showing when I touch left edge of screen?

Tags: launcher, unity-2d

One of the things I really liked about 11.04 was how I could make the Launcher only show when I moved the mouse to a corner. In 11.10 Unity-2D the Launcher shows every time my mouse goes against the left edge of the screen--this results in the Launcher always sliding out when I don't want it to.

I tried installing CCSM but it appears not to work with Unity-2D. And, although I find it hard to believe that no such setting exists, I can find no setting that will disable the left-edge trigger.

Is there a way to move the trigger to the bottom-left corner or even disable the trigger completely? I'd actually prefer to just press the Super key and access the Launcher that way.

Comment: Unity 2D is not built over Compiz, so CCSM won't work

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, afaik that is not possible. There are some (very limited) options about the hiding mode of the launcher in the dconf-editor (->com->canonical->unity-2D->launcher).

- **never hide**; the launcher is always visible. [...]
- **auto hide**; the launcher will disappear after a short time if the user is not interacting with it
- **intellihide**; the launcher will disappear if a window is placed on top of it and if the user is not interacting with it